# ¿"Como que / si" con subjuntivo o indicativo?

Tags: subjuntivo, conjunciones

Leí en mis libros y en línea que las conjunciones "como que" y "como si" son usados con subjuntivo, por exemplo:

**Ella lo mira como si lo conociera.**

Pero en el mismo libro encontré la frase siguiente:

**El hacía como que no lo oía.**

Me parece que esto es indicativo, ¿no? Buscar en google me ha confundido más. ¿Puedo usar ambos, modo subjuntivo y indicativo? ¿O tal vez algo se me escapó?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no es una respuesta definitiva. Pero considera los siguientes ejemplos:

> 1. Ella lo mira como si lo conociera. Correcto.
> 2. Ella lo mira como que lo conociera. Incorrecto. (Entonces *como si* y *como que* **no** son lo mismo)
> 3. Él hacía como que no lo oía. Correcto.
> 4. Él hacía como que no lo oyera. Incorrecto.
> 5. Él hacía como si no lo oyera. Correcto.

Lo que arruina la regla es que *como si* y *como que* no siempre son intercambiables.

También es bueno notar que *hacer como que* o *hacer como si* son dos expresiones que significan *fingir*.

---

Hay dos puntos adicionales que pretendo pulir después:

1 . De acuerdo a la información obtenida en el chat, la regla dice que *como si* induce `subjuntivo`. Por otra parte, el verbo que sigue a *como que* (aunque es equivalente a *como si*) no tiene por qué estar en `subjuntivo`

2 . Ahora, ¿por qué es correcta también la siguiente frase?

> Él hacía como si no lo oía. (Correcto.)

¿Por qué la anterior suena extraño?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me lo ayudó mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que cualquiera de los dos son válidos. Tampoco encuentro mucha diferencia en significado entre "él hacía como que no lo oía" y "él hace como si no lo oyera" más que el tiempo pasado y presente respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias. Y "Él hacía como que no lo oyera", ¿es correcto también? ... Sólo para entenderlo todo.

Comment: Creo que no viola ninguna regla, pero si lo escucho hablado me suena muy raro (por lo menos en Uruguay).

Comment: @GregorBruns Con el subjuntivo no suena natural. Quizá sea correcto, pero el indicativo en este caso es lo mejor.

Comment: @mathinfonseca ambos son pasados (pretérito imperfecto), sólo que el primero en indicativo y el segundo en subjuntivo.

Comment: @c.p.: ¿Puede formular una regla, por favor? Me extraña que el uso de subjuntivo o indicativo detrás de una preposición se cambie si el tiempo de la oración principal lo hace. Además, en los exemplos de mathifonseca, el primer tiene dos pasados, pero el segundo tiene un pasado y un presente, ¿no?

Comment: @GregorBruns Sobre los tiempos del verbo **oír** en la respuesta de mathinfonseca, ambos son pretérito imperfecto (subjuntivo e indicativo). Los otros *hace* y *hacía*, son presente y pasado pero tu pregunta no se refiere a esos tiempos.

Comment: @GregorBruns For discussion over the rule, [let's go to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12297/subjuntivo)